# Whether to say "Еще даже не вечер, а ..." or "Еще даже не вечером, а ..."

Tags: грамматика

> Еще даже не **вечер**, а ты уже выпиваешь.
>
> Еще даже не **вечером**, а ты уже выпиваешь.

I'm wondering if I should use the noun "вечер" or the adverb "вечером" to express the idea of "not in the evening". Incidentally, should I see "вечером" as the instrumental noun instead?

Comment: Еще даже не вечер , а ты уже выпиваешь///Мы с тобой выпьем, но вечером, а не сейчас///Ты уже выпиваешь, а ведь пока еще только день, а не вечер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sound natural, you'd want simplier expressions "ещё не вечер" and "ещё день".

The 1st one, besides "it's (relatively) early yet [to/for something]", has an alternative meaning in colloquial, "there's yet time [to/for something]".

The 2nd one means "it's daytime yet".

Answer (score 2):

The first phrase can be translated as "it's not even evening and you are already drinking." It's constructed pretty much similar to it's English counterpart and `вечер` is in the nominative case.

The second phrase is ungrammatical - you are confusing [`вечером`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC) (which as you mentioned as an adverb) and the noun [`вечер`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80#Russian). The adverb stands for `in the evening.`

Answer (score 1):

We are omitting words, mostly the verb to be (is).

"Ещё не вечер" means "[NOW IT IS] not an evening yet"

"Ещё не вечером" is just incorrect. We can say "Вечером" (In the evening), "Не вечером" (Not in the evening), but we it doesn't match with "Ещё".